# Foreign Key Issues with Application User

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using entity framework core and code first to make some tables.

I want one table with two Foreign keys, with both being the application user.

I have it built and running, but every time I try to add to the table I get an error

```
SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ApplicationUser'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ApplicationUser'. The duplicate key value is (ef20a79d-e819-499d-b006-c32f5cf85577).
```

This might just be a database design issue, but I feel like that I am doing this should work.

Here is the models:

```
    public class Test
    {
        public string TestId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Giver")]
        public string GiverId { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser Giver { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Getter")]
        public string GetterId { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser Getter { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the ApplicationUser class
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [InverseProperty("Giver")]
        public ICollection<CustomModels.Test> Giver { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("Getter")]
        public ICollection<CustomModels.Test> Getter { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the code to create the table:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Tests",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    TestId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    GetterId = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    GiverId = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Tests", x => x.TestId);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Tests_ApplicationUser_GetterId",
                        column: x => x.GetterId,
                        principalTable: "ApplicationUser",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Tests_ApplicationUser_GiverId",
                        column: x => x.GiverId,
                        principalTable: "ApplicationUser",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                });


            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Tests_GetterId",
                table: "Tests",
                column: "GetterId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Tests_GiverId",
                table: "Tests",
                column: "GiverId");
```

This is how I am adding to the DB:

```
Test test = (new Test
{
    Giver = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User),
    Getter = await _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email == "s@gmail.com")
});
_context.Tests.Add(test);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I would like to be able to track which user is giving information and which user is getting information.

We were using just the user email for tracking, but we would have to search for the email every time and I feel like this would be a better long-term solution.

I should be able to add as my "test" rows and repeat users, ie user1 can give to user2 and vise-versa, and that would be 2 different rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is `_userManager.GetUserAsync(User)` isn't operating on the same `DbContext` as `_context`. So `_context` isn't aware of that `ApplicationUser` and will try to create it. The resolution to this would be to `Attach` the ApplicationUser before saving.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't even think about the two contexts. I just added it all under one context to reduce problems.